# Keeping a spare laptop battery at home

Tags: battery, battery-life

What is the best way to keep a newly bought spare laptop battery at home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rechargeable battery. Store it in a cool place and it should be fine for a year to 18 months and possibly beyond for good batteries.

Charge before using when you first use it.

I have rechargeable batteries in little use electronic and power equipment and the batteries are good whenever I charge them first.

Comment: For long-term storage, initial charge to 80% is recommended.. though not that easy to actually achieve unless you're watching it like paint drying ;-) Recharge every 3-6 months back to 80%

Comment: 1 year to 18 months seems pretty short. I have plenty of laptops that used the same charger for 5+ years. Do batteries have a shorter lifespan when not used?

Comment: Probably not but I like to keep expectations reasonable. It was purely an estimate and good batteries can last longer.

Comment: I have several Li-Ion batteries in equipment in my basement (projects over) and they are fine if I charge them up before using them.